# Excel survey data pivoting, plotting and analysis

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, pivot-table, survey

I have a set of data from Google forms survey. I ran into a problem representing the data for a specific question type, grid to be exact.

So for example you get a question like [this one:](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1g2tonDqzfr8fl0AbRgAiqfb0NYC07nNunlBCQXcH0I4/viewform?usp=send_form)

[image: form]

and Google collects all the data into a spreadsheet like this:

[image: data]

Then I go ahead and download it in .xlsx format to make sense of all of it. Trying to pivot it around is not doing what I exactly expect it to do, as it simply counts "yes" and "no" from the first column, and copying that to second and third.

I get something like this:

[image: pivoting data]

I've spent some time looking online and trying to figure out pivot tables, and for the most part I can use it just fine, but this is giving me trouble.
I found a way to use Excel findif() function to create a new table from raw data and then manipulate it around, but this approach looks like it's prone to human errors.

This is the result, and what I would like to get from raw data without manually juggling the data around:

[image: findif function]

To get a better understanding of my problem you can [download](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=bd8c927f0799bede&id=BD8C927F0799BEDE!147), or look at the spreadsheet online.

Comment: Excel pivot table can't manage data in the same row as independent, so solving your problem with standard pivot table is not really possible. Solution for your problem would require un-pivoting the data first (1st column: question (purchase, preparation, waste), second one: answer (yes, no). You can find plenty of solutions for that on the internet, however I think all of them are more prone to errors then your current workaround. To improve your current solution you can use array formulas which are more protected against accidental changes.

Comment: Is it required in some way to use pivot tables? You could just setup a table with some (not too hard) formula's and create a chart based on that. That would give you exactly what you want, and it would work even if you add data.

Comment: @agtoever Pivot tables are not a requirement, but it looked like good way to easily represent and cross data in different ways. This is just a simplified example of a typical question, but throughout the paper I would need to refer to the same data and represent it differently. Writing formulas and functions for each view seems tedious and error prone as there is more than 50 columns from survey alone.

Comment: I understand. See my answer below, which explains why pivot tables are not suitable for data that is structured in that way and an alternative approach to process your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a more error proof formula compared to your original one, as it will really summarize columns and variables which are mentioned in the header and first column, you can't change them by mistake. Worst case can happen if you mistype something that you get error or 0.

`=COUNTIF(INDEX(Tabela2[#All],0,MATCH($E2,Tabela2[#Headers],0)),F$1)`, where:

- `MATCH($E2,Tabela2[#Headers],0))` - looks for the column of original table specified in the first column
- `INDEX(Tabela2[#All],0,MATCH(...))` - get the address of this found column
- `=COUNTIF(INDEX(...),F$1)` - count number of occurrences of header data in the column.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @mátéjuhász, Pivot tables don't work well with data that is already "pivioted". You'll need to flatten your table to have the columns: question; answer to get the pivot table to work in the way you want.

As an alternative, you can create a very simple table yourself, that takes the data from your source table and prepares the data for charting. As you see in the screenshot below, this gives you the right results. In practice, I'd put the intermediate table and the chart all if separate worksheets.

In each of the cell's in the table is the following formula: `COUNTIF(<name_of_your_table>[<column_title>];[@answer])` (replace the `<...>` with the correct values). For example in the purchase column, I have `COUNTIF(Tabela2[purchase];[@answer])`

[image: Solution screenshot]